# name of the class that contains the method code

Tags: python, introspection

I'm trying to find the name of the class that contains method code.

In the example underneath I use `self.__class__.__name__`, but of course this returns the name of the class of which self is an instance and not class that contains the `test()` method code. `b.test()` will print `'B'` while I would like to get `'A'`.

I looked into the `inspect` module documentation but did not find anything directly useful.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def test(self):
    print self.__class__.__name__

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    A.__init__(self)



a = A()
b = B()

a.test()
b.test()
```

Comment: You know this at coding time, no? It's A: `def test(self): print "A"`.

Comment: I want to avoid to replicate the class name. If I change the class name from `A` to `AA` I'll be the first to forget to adept the `print "A"` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you can simply use `__class__.__name__`. The `__class__` name is mildly magic, and not the same thing as the `__class__` attribute of `self`.

In Python 2.x, there is no good way to get at that information. You can use stack inspection to get the code object, then walk the class hierarchy looking for the right method, but it's slow and tedious and will probably break when you don't want it to. You can also use a metaclass or a class decorator to post-process the class in some way, but both of those are rather intrusive approaches. And you can do something really ugly, like accessing `self.__nonexistant_attribute`, catching the AttributeError and extracting the class name from the mangled name. None of those approaches are really worth it if you just want to avoid typing the name twice; at least forgetting to update the name can be made a little more obvious by doing something like:

```
class C:
    ...
    def report_name(self):
        print C.__name__
```

Answer (score 4):

[inspect.getmro](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect.getmro#inspect.getmro) gives you a tuple of the classes where the method might come from, in order.  As soon as you find one of them that has the method's name in its `dict`, you're done:

```
for c in inspect.getmro(self.__class__):
    if 'test' in vars(c): break
return c.__name__
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives you the name of the first class in the MRO that has an attribute with that name, which is not necessarily the same as the method you're doing this from (if your method is farther down the MRO.)

Comment: Nice solution, but as Thomas mentions it does not work when `class B` overrides the `test()` method:

    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def test(self):
            import inspect
            for c in inspect.getmro(self.__class__):
                if 'test' in vars(c):
                    break
            print c.__name__
 
    
    class B(A):
        def __init__(self):
            A.__init__(self)
        def test(self):
            A.test(self)

    
    
a = A()
b = B()

a.test()   # prints A
b.test()   # prints B

Comment: sorry for the mess in previous comment. This is my first stackoverflow comment and I was not aware of the inability to add code in comments.

Comment: @kdlp, when class B overrides `test`, then calling `test` on an instance of B does run the code in `B.test`, so B **is** "the class that contains the method code" being executed.  That's what you're asking for!

Comment: @Thomas, I don't understand your comment -- the class that contains the method code for `someinstance.test()` _is_ the first one defining `test` along the MRO (that code may delegate to other functions, including one or more superclasses' versions of some other method with the same name, but "the method code" for `test` is that "first one", quite apart from what other methods or functions it chooses to call).

Comment: If `class A:` and `class B(A):` both define the method `test`, and `A.test`, not `B.test`, tries your method of looking up "its own class", it finds `B`, *not* `A`.

Comment: @Thomas, exactly.  What I don't get is why this behavior is supposed to be wrong: it finds exactly the same class (defining `test`) as Python attribute access does.

Comment: Indeed it does, but that doesn't mean it's the answer the OP wanted :) The OP quite clearly asked for "the class *this method* is defined in", not "the most derived class that defines a method with this name".

Answer (score 2):

Use `__dict__` of class object itself:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    pass

def find_decl_class(cls, method):
    if method in cls.__dict__:
        return cls
    for b in cls.__bases__:
        decl = find_decl_class(b, method)
        if decl:
            return decl

print 'foo' in A.__dict__
print 'foo' in B.__dict__
print find_decl_class(B, 'foo').__name__
```

Will print True, False, A

Comment: This has the same problem as Alex's MRO solution.

Comment: Agree. But if it is known in advance that there will be just single-class inheritance, solution is OK and simple. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2):

You can use (abuse?) [private name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) to accomplish this effect. If you look up an attribute on `self` that starts with `__` from inside a method, python changes the name from `__attribute` to `_classThisMethodWasDefinedIn__attribute`.

Just somehow stash the classname you want in mangled-form where the method can see it. As an example, we can define a `__new__` method on the base class that does it:

```
def mangle(cls, attrname):
    if not attrname.startswith('__'):
        raise ValueError('attrname must start with __')
    return '_%s%s' % (cls.__name__, attrname)

class A(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        for c in cls.mro():
            setattr(obj, mangle(c, '__defn_classname'), c.__name__)
        return obj

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self):
        print self.__defn_classname

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)



a = A()
b = B()

a.test()
b.test()
```

which prints:

```
A
A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     pass
...   def test(self):
...     for b in self.__class__.__bases__:
...       if hasattr(b, 'test'):
...         return b.__name__
...     return self.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     A.__init__(self)
...
>>> B().test()
'A'
>>> A().test()
'A'
>>>
```

Keep in mind that you could simplify it by using `__class__.__base__`, but if you use multiple inheritance, this version will work better.

It simply checks first on its baseclasses for `test`. It's not the prettiest, but it works.